# JQuery Bracket plugin - init property from a function result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, brackets

I'm trying to initialize the render object with the result of a JS function that returns a query from a REST service

[JS function that returns a query from a REST service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fpob.png)

This is the function that initializes the object:

[Function that initializes the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ATs9.png)

In the console log I have this result:

[Console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8edTL.png)

The expected result would be this :(

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zhVn.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in assigning a variable within an asynchronous call. I moved a call from the object's startup function to the success of the function calling the service and it worked.